# Why does Input from an AlertDialog not show in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

I want to take input from an AlertDialog box and set it to 2 variables then use those variables as an argument to make a list using recyclerview.

With the code in its this state it brings up the dialogbox and when i enter information and press "add" nothing shows onto the screen.

Here is my Java file:

```
public class tab1Expenses extends Fragment {
List<ExRow> expenseList = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ExpensesAdapter mAdapter;
Button btnEx;
EditText txtExName;
EditText txtExAmount;

public void expenseData() {

    ExRow exs = new ExRow(txtExNa, txtExAm);
    expenseList.add(exs);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1expense, container, false);
    btnEx = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnEx);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    mAdapter = new ExpensesAdapter(expenseList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new RecyclerView.LayoutManager() {
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {

            return null;
        }

    };
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    btnEx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(tab1Expenses.this.getActivity())
                    .inflate(R.layout.add_ex, null);
            txtExName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.exName);
            txtExAmount = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.exAmount);
            AlertDialog.Builder add = new AlertDialog.Builder(tab1Expenses.this.getActivity());
                    add.setCancelable(true)
                    .setTitle("Enter Expense:")
                    .setView(view)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    expenseData();
                                }
                            });
            Dialog dialog = add.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
   }
}
```

---

Here is the related XML file:

```
<Button
    android:text="Add Expense"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnEx"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:width="800dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Switch"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

---

And the XML file for adding inputs:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/exName"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:editable="false"
        android:hint="Expense Name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/exAmount"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:hint="Expense Amount" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You state that your app crashes.  Please edit your question to include the entire error and stack trace from such a crash.  It will help people to give you good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the reference for `txtExName` and `txtExAmount` from **`view`** not `rootview`. So from your latest code remove these lines

```
txtExName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.exName); 
txtExAmount = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.exAmount);
```

and add these lines on same spot.

```
txtExName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.exName); 
txtExAmount = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.exAmount);
```

Comment: thank you. The app no longer crashes from input, but nothing appears in the recyclerview.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so as I can see the issue is due to it not being able to find `EditText` named `txtExName`, and `txtExAmount`. So,

cut these two lines:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
txtExName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.exName); //<---This one
txtExAmount = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.exAmount); // <--And this one
```

and replace them with these:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(tab1Expenses.this.getActivity())
                .inflate(R.layout.add_ex, null);
txtExName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.exName);
txtExAmount = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.exAmount);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please add log stacktrace? Then maybe we can help.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.ojemz.expensetracker.tab1Expenses.expenseData(tab1Expenses.java:34)
                                                                                    at com.example.ojemz.expensetracker.tab1Expenses$2$1.onClick(tab1Expenses.java:81)

Comment: txtExNa = (txtExName.getText()).toString(); <-- this line is the problem. It's apparently getting a null value?

Answer (score 0):

where are yours EditTexts in you XML file posted?

Probably it's return null because it's not finding any EditText:

```
String txtExNa = (txtExAmount.getText()).toString(); //here is crash, i think
```

Sorry my english and I hope this help!

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't include that. Let me update the question

Answer (score 0):

OK so this may be final answer. I will try to cover up everything you are trying to do.

//This is `tab1expense.xml` (Without toolbar)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:text="Add Expense"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnEx"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Switch"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_green_light" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

//This is `add_ex.xml` (Used in popup)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/exName"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:editable="false"
        android:hint="Expense Name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/exAmount"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:hint="Expense Amount" />

</LinearLayout>
```

//Now a Class called `ExRow.java`

```
public class ExRow{

    String str_txtExNa,str_txtExAm;

    ExRow(String str_txtExNa, String str_txtExAm){
        this.str_txtExNa=str_txtExNa;
        this.str_txtExAm=str_txtExAm;
    }

    public String getNa()
    {
       return str_txtExNa;
    }

    public String getAm()
    {
      return str_txtExAm;
    }
}
```

//Now your `tab1Expenses.java`

```
public class tab1Expenses extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<ExRow> expenseList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ExpensesAdapter mAdapter;
    Button btnEx;
    EditText txtExName;
    EditText txtExAmount;

    public void expenseData(String txtExNa,String txtExAm) {
        ExRow exs = new ExRow(txtExNa, txtExAm);
        expenseList.add(exs);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1expense, container, false);
    btnEx = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnEx);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    mAdapter = new ExpensesAdapter(expenseList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    btnEx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(tab1Expenses.this.getActivity())
                    .inflate(R.layout.add_ex, null);
            txtExName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.exName);
            txtExAmount = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.exAmount);
            AlertDialog.Builder add = new AlertDialog.Builder(tab1Expenses.this.getActivity());
                    add.setCancelable(true)
                    .setTitle("Enter Expense:")
                    .setView(view)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    expenseData(txtExName.getText().toString(),txtExAmount`enter code here`.getText().toString() );
                                }
                            });
            Dialog dialog = add.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
   }
}
```

//`row_item_view.xml` (Layout for row View of RecyclerView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_amount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

//Finally the Adapter Class i.e, `ExpensesAdapter.java`

```
public class ExpensesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExpensesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ExRow> expenseList;

    // Constructor of the class
    public ExpensesAdapter(ArrayList<ExRow> expenseList) {
        this.expenseList = expenseList;
    }

    // get the size of the list
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return expenseList == null ? 0 : expenseList.size();
    }


    // specify the row layout file
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item_view, parent, false);
        ViewHolder myViewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    // load data in each row element
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {
        holder.row_name.setText(expenseList.get(listPosition).getNa());
        holder.row_amount.setText(expenseList.get(listPosition).getAm());
    }

    // Static inner class to initialize the views of rows
    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView row_name,row_amount;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            row_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_name);
            row_amount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_amount);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this finally solves the issue.